# Form::file notsending file to controller! Laravel5

Tags: php, laravel

```
$file = \Request::file('media')->getClientOriginalName();
```

For some reason, laravel (5) keeps coming back with

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object

I have dumped `$file` to see if anything has been passed, and is coming back `NULL`! Here is the Blade HTML Form code :

```
{!! Form::file('media' , array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')) !!}
```

**Update:**

If I use

```
Request::get
```

Then I get :

> string(29) code-wallpaper-20-610x381.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after a long and frustrating battle, I have found a solution. I dont know why this works, and I'm not sure what I changed to make it work, but I'll post what I did anyways.

In the

```
{{ Form::open }}
```

Add

```
'file' => 'true'
```

in your array. Also replace

```
\Request::file()
```

with

```
\Input::file()
```

and I updated composer too! Don't think it fixed the issue, but just posted it in case as it was one of the things I tried!

Comment: Adding `'file' => true` is the critical bit here.